# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de sumar cantidades en un array de jsons?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Teniendo por ejemplo este array de jsons:

```
var producto = [
  {
    id: '5e87b26c2855bd6f6bc4feff',
    fecha: '2020-04-03T22:02:20.221Z',
    total: 22.85,
    productos: [
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Hamburguesa Big' },
      { cantidad: 2, nombre: 'Ensalada Cesar' },
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Soda Fanta 12 onz' },
      { cantidad: 2, nombre: 'Refresco de Horchata' },
      { cantidad: 4, nombre: 'Pilsener' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5e87b37f2855bd6f6bc4ff00',
    fecha: '2020-04-03T22:06:55.647Z',
    total: 13.99,
    productos: [
      { cantidad: 8, nombre: 'Pilsener' },
      { cantidad: 4, nombre: 'Hamburguesa Big' },
      { cantidad: 6, nombre: 'Ensalada Cesar' },
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Choripan 30 cm' },
    ],
  },
]
```

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de sacar un top de productos más vendidos y que el output sean 2 valores, el nombre del producto y la cantidad? Como por ejemplo:

- 'Pilsener': 12
- 'Ensalada Cesar': 8
- 'Hamburguesa Big': 5
- 'Refresco de Horchata': 2
- 'Soda Fanta 12 onz': 1
- 'Choripan 30 cm': 1

De antemano les agradezco por cualquier sugerencia. Cualquier idea es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta es una buena manera de ordenarlos, usando el metodo `sort` de los `arrays`, checa esto:

```js
const productos = [
  {
    id: '5e87b26c2855bd6f6bc4feff',
    fecha: '2020-04-03T22:02:20.221Z',
    total: 22.85,
    productos: [
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Hamburguesa Big' },
      { cantidad: 2, nombre: 'Ensalada Cesar' },
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Soda Fanta 12 onz' },
      { cantidad: 2, nombre: 'Refresco de Horchata' },
      { cantidad: 4, nombre: 'Pilsener' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5e87b37f2855bd6f6bc4ff00',
    fecha: '2020-04-03T22:06:55.647Z',
    total: 13.99,
    productos: [
      { cantidad: 8, nombre: 'Pilsener' },
      { cantidad: 4, nombre: 'Hamburguesa Big' },
      { cantidad: 6, nombre: 'Ensalada Cesar' },
      { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Choripan 30 cm' },
    ],
  },
]

function ordenarPorClave(clave, arregloObjetos, ordenarMenorAMayor = false){
    return arregloObjetos.sort((a, b) => {
      return ordenarMenorAMayor == false ? b[clave] - a[clave] : a[clave] - b[clave]; 
    });
}

const todosLosProductos = productos.map(producto => producto.productos).flat();
const topProductos = ordenarPorClave("cantidad", todosLosProductos);
console.log(topProductos);
```

la función ordenar por clave ordena ya sea de mayor a menor o de menor a mayor según el tercer parametro que le diste a la función, si es falso ordenara de mayor a menor por defecto, si es verdadero ordenara de menor a mayor el array de objetos.

a la función sort de array se le puede pasar un callback a manera de poder hacer un ordenamiento personalizado, en nuestro caso el ordenamiento personalizado lo hacemos por medio de una clave de nuestro arreglo de objetos, en este caso una numerica:

```
function ordenarPorClave(clave, arregloObjetos, ordenarMenorAMayor = false){
    return arregloObjetos.sort((a, b) => {
      return ordenarMenorAMayor == false ? b[clave] - a[clave] : a[clave] - b[clave]; 
    });
}
```

donde `a` contiene los primeros elementos del array hasta el penultimo, y `b`, contiene los parametros desde el segundo elemento hasta el ultimo, ya entonces te estaras dando una idea de como funciona la función sort... valga la redundanciá.

Seguidamente para poder tener todos los productos en una lista, primero debemos coleccionarlos en un array unico, para ello hacemos lo siguiente:

```
const todosLosProductos = productos.map(producto => producto.productos).flat();
```

la función map es una función que se ejecutara para todos los elementos de un array, es como un foreach pero mejor, aparte lo que hace es retornar un arreglo con elementos personalizados según nosotros se lo ordenemos, sin embargo el arreglo personalizado que nos devuelve map, esta dentro de otro arreglo, lo cuál no nos interesa, lo que nos interesa es que nos devuelva un solo arreglo que contenga todos los objetos, para lo cual, al final de que se ejecute map, utilizamos la función flat, para aplanar el array:

```
productos.map(producto => producto.productos).flat();
```

Ahora ya tendriamos la lista entera de productos desordenada en un arreglo de objetos.

Lo unico que tenemos que hacer ahora es ordenar nuestro arreglo de objetos, usando la función que habiamos creado para ello:

```
const topProductos = ordenarPorClave("cantidad", todosLosProductos);
console.log(topProductos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo aprecio mucho.

Comment: De nada, recuerda que si te fue de ayuda la respuesta puedes darla como aceptada, dandole al boton que parece un chulo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `Array.reduce` para sacar una lista *flat* de todos los productos

```
const flat = productos.reduce((stack, curr) => [...stack.productos, ...curr.productos])
```

Básicamente, recorre cada elemento del `productos` y crea un nuevo *array* con la deconstrucción del acumulado y la deconstrucción del array `productos` del elemento actual.

Sobre ese nuevo *array*, podemos aplicar el típico algoritmo de búsqueda y actualización, para sumar las cantidades.

```
const result = [];
flat.forEach(product => {
    const found = result.find(p => p.nombre === product.nombre);
    if (found)
        found.cantidad += product.cantidad;
    else 
        result.push(product);
});
```

Finalmente, `result` tiene una lista de los productos con las cantidades sumadas:

```
[
  { cantidad: 5, nombre: 'Hamburguesa Big' },
  { cantidad: 8, nombre: 'Ensalada Cesar' },
  { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Soda Fanta 12 onz' },
  { cantidad: 2, nombre: 'Refresco de Horchata' },
  { cantidad: 12, nombre: 'Pilsener' },
  { cantidad: 1, nombre: 'Choripan 30 cm' }
]
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder, muy amable.